# Run an extra where clause in the model

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to specify a where clause for the model to run with each select?
Example:
I have a query `$var = TestModal::where('date', '2021-06-08')->get();` and I want my `TestModal` to run `->where('type', 'r')` for every query so I don't have to write it multiple times

Comment: this is what query scope intend to be:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#writing-global-scopes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [Anonymous Global Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#anonymous-global-scopes) to define the query for each Query running on the Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TestModal extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('type', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('type', 'r');
        });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use multiple where like this

```
    var = TestModal->where(['date' => '2021-06-08', 'type' => '' ])->get();
    
or
    
    var = TestModal->where('date' , '2021-06-08' )->where('type' , '')->get();

or can your addGlobalScope

 protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('table_name', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('type', ');
        });
    }
```